# How to query Firestore for value in array

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Per Firebase Firestore docs, in order to query a collection where an array contains a certain value, you'd do this:

`citiesRef.whereField("regions", arrayContains: "west_coast")`

Only when I try to write that in Swift 4, I get the following error:

`Argument labels '(_:, arrayContains:)' do not match any available overloads`

Looking at the available overloads yields the following:

```
Query whereField(field: String, isEqualTo: Any)
Query whereField(path: FieldPath, isEqualTo: Any)
Query whereField(field: String, isLessThan: Any)
Query whereField(path: FieldPath, isLessThan: Any)
Query whereField(field: String, isGreaterThan: Any)
Query whereField(path: FieldPath, isGreaterThan: Any)
Query whereField(field: String, isLessThanOrEqualTo: Any)
Query whereField(path: FieldPath, isLessThanOrEqualTo: Any)
Query whereField(field: String, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Any)
Query whereField(path: FieldPath, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: Any)
```

Nothing in there about arrays or contains. Are the docs out of date? What am I missing? [Docs found here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

My Podfile:

```
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Appname' do
use_frameworks!

# Pods for Appname

pod ‘Firebase/Core’
pod ‘Firebase/Auth’
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Invites'
pod 'SwiftGifOrigin', '~> 1.6'
pod 'Kingfisher', '~> 4.0'
pod 'AudioKit', '~> 4.0'
pod 'KSTokenView', '~> 4.0'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
pod 'ZFTokenField'
pod 'SlackTextViewController'
pod 'RealmSwift'

target 'AppnameTests' do
 inherit! :search_paths
 # Pods for testing
end

target 'AppnameUITests' do
 inherit! :search_paths
 # Pods for testing
end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

arrayContains support was released in 5.5.0 of the Firestore pod.  Make sure you are using that version or later.  [Read the release notes here.](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios)

Comment: Ok, I added `pod 'Firebase/Firestore'` to my podfile yesterday according to the docs. Shouldn't that give me the latest version?

Comment: What does your podfile say?

Comment: I looked in the terminal and it says:
`Firebase 4.11.0
FirebaseCore 4.0.18
FirebaseFirestore 0.10.4`

I ran pod update and that didn't do anything, do I need to add a version after my `Firebase/Core` pod?

Comment: Whoa. You've got some pretty old podfiles there. You might need to update cocoapods itself. If that doesn't work, try explicitly running a `pod repo update` before you run a pod update. And if _that_ doesn't work, please share the entire contents of your podfile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work. I pasted my entire podfile above.

Comment: Stupid mistake, for some reason I didn't have `pod 'Firebase'` in my podfile. Added that and it works. Thanks.